# Lagrange multipliers for Bose-Einstein distribution

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> We have $$ W = \prod_{s=1}^N \frac{(g_s-1+n_s)!}{(g_s-1)!n_s!}  $$ For $ g_s,n_s>>1 $. We also have the constraints $$ \sum_{s=1}^Nn_s = n \hspace{10mm} \sum_{s=1}^Nn_sE_s = E $$ We are to show $ \ln{W}$ is greatest for $$ \boxed{n_s = g_s\left[e^{\beta(E_s-\mu)}-1\right]^{-1}}$$ Where $\beta$ and $\beta\mu$ are Lagrange multipliers.

I have managed to reduce $\ln{W}$, using Stirling's approximation of $\ln{n!}=n\ln{n} - n$,  to a horrible looking: $$ \ln{W} = \sum_{s=1}^N\left[(g_s-1+n_s)\ln{(g_s-1+n_s)} -(g_s-1)\ln{(g_s-1) -n_s\ln{n_s}}\right]$$ However, trying to use Lagrange multipliers gives an even worse expression. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $g_s,n_s>>1$, we have
$$W = \prod_{s=1}^N \frac{(g_s-1+n_s)!}{(g_s-1)!n_s!}\approx\prod_{s=1}^N \frac{(g_s+n_s)!}{g_s!n_s!}$$ 
Using Stirling's approximation will then result in
$$\ln{W} = \sum_{s=1}^N\left[(g_s+n_s)\ln{(g_s+n_s)} -g_s\ln{(g_s-1) -n_s\ln{n_s}}\right]$$
Consider the Lagrangian (where $\beta$ and $\lambda$ are the two Lagrange multipliers)
$$\mathcal{L}=\ln{W}+\beta(E-\sum_{s=1}^Nn_sE_s)+\lambda(n-\sum_{s=1}^Nn_s)$$
Differentiating $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $n_s$ and setting this to $0$ results in
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial n_s}=\ln(g_s+n_s)-\ln n_s-\beta E_s-\lambda&=0\\\Rightarrow\ln\left(\frac{g_s+n_s}{n_s}\right)&=\beta E_s+\lambda\\\Rightarrow n_s&=g_s[e^{\beta E_s+\lambda}-1]^{-1}\end{align}$$
Without loss of generality, we can set $\lambda$ to $-\mu\beta$ leading to
$$n_s=g_s[e^{\beta (E_s-\mu)}-1]^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this. However, why do we no longer have the sum in the differential of the lagrangian? I.e the sigmas are no longer there

Comment: The sigmas are no longer there as we are differentiating with respect to $n_s$ for a single value of the index $s$. The rest of the summation terms disappear (i.e. $n_k$ for $\forall k\neq s$).

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You are most welcome.